# How to count char tuples efficiently in PHP

Tags: php, performance, n-gram

I need to fast count char tuples (or N-grams) in huge files/strings (from 10MB+ up to 1GB+) within a PHP project (a file classifier).

The current implementation is made for single characters count (N=1), and runs very fast in 0.x sec. on very large strings (up to 1 billion chars/bytes)

```php
// returns an associative array [char => count]
function frequencies($txt) {
  $index = count_chars($txt, 1);
  foreach ($index as $code => $nb) {
    $count[chr($code)] = $nb;
  }
  return $count;
}
```

I'd like to modify it to run with bigrams (N=2 or more), so I wrote this

```php
// returns an associative array [charTuple => count]
function frequencies($txt, $n) {
    $length = strlen($txt) - $n+1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        @$count [ substr($txt, $i, $n) ] ++;
    }
    return $count;
}
// NB: '@' is ugly but seems faster than if isset()
```

However this code is really slow: 45 sec. on the same file for N = 1 (about 100x slower) and more than a minute for N=2.

I have tried a direct access + concatenation alternative:

```php
function twograms($txt) {
    $length = strlen($txt) - $n;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        @$count [ $txt[$i] . $txt[$i+1] ] ++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

And it runs slightly faster in 42 sec. (+/- error margin)

It is still way too slow and does not match the built-in function `count_char()` efficiency.

Is there an alternative ? Is there a way to count char tuples more efficiently ?

**EDIT**: I updated the [online PHP link to test/benchmark](https://onlinephp.io?s=tVRdb9owFH0Gif9whYJwlMBIRruPlq3a634CQ5FxHJKVOKntdNCt_33-CoQibeu28oCu4-Pjc87NzfXHOq8HfU_uJCxASJ6IvMmyLUW65rSmWKLhLIpfzy8u37x9h9ckpdkmL77ebktW1XdcyOb-227_MAwhmqmf719pPiqkUIzLMakaJhOSY55E4xDGollralOnBadEJpgQKoTb1hLqbSFP0PE5Oj5Fx-OVujerOMUkB-QEYAGm8uH7oA8lLSu-V64ElYlydps0Am8o0orBExJzHUJZEF7JoqQoshsKrx4bHqSDMk9rXjCZoeEongnkww8YRdOLDAQlU7Vg6_cwmqeqUneq8jKFz5--MJWRoQlPLpnYq0MwUSF9nx8CV4sUOcmbJ4JfRbN4bpJ-HPSV7YYRWVQMumFbrcY4eAVL6U65OAKE2VdNM3bgmJyF6uRIlVJYfACPrR2PYso4vVuSnCOz7a90NGxtOB71H6ey4czizvS1ze9qA29L2Ubm9v1T9TFkI0tLUnuzK-UCrlu0XgXBQRbAjVXmrnDmvEIbhFUQWDqj8NcSn7yTL6hUH156xepZ8jrzcSLNHcKc431iu3yPtw0V6HDC4s9fmnbG_sAqTCD6b42J_6UxL6320JxpWwbR33aqo7Xnmd7oD8pvW6UT0t3qtV_nboBRCBM3uso-23BcPosUoDvz7rweelOaqTcsh2h6N0760kJWECwcxtEp-702EQvVmfwE) to take into account the proposal with `str_split` and `array_count_values` and the associated memory usage.

Comment: I'm curious why you need this? Cryptanalysis?

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, like what would be the result?

Comment: @Elikill58 An n-gram is a sequence of n adjacent symbols in a particular order. Crypto seems to be counting the occurrence of each unique n-gram here.

Comment: You could try to do this with array functions. First use [str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split) to access the n-grams, shifting n-1 times forward in the `$txt` value, and then use [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). This is memory intensive, so you might want to process each splitted array separately.

Comment: I did some testing on the solution I proposed above. I have to conclude that it is _very_ memory intensive and the speed is comparable to your other solutions. Perhaps PHP isn't the best language to use?

Comment: @Olivier, its a part of a file analyser for a machine learning/classifier tool. The goal is to fast process the content of a file and infer data/classification from chars count.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware PHP is really fast for single char, but yes, maybe its not the right language for processing chars couples.

Comment: I saw your update, and noted you get the same results as I did. If you want more speed you need to use a language that can be far more efficient, like C.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the performance, but you could include this approach when you're benchmarking alternatives.  It uses a combination of `str_split` and `array_count_values` to count sequences of chars in the source string:

```php
$str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

$len = 2;
$counts = [];
for ($n = 0; $n < $len; $n++) {
    $ngramCounts = array_count_values(str_split(substr($str, $n), $len));
    foreach ($ngramCounts as $ngram => $count) {
        $counts[$ngram] = ($counts[$ngram] ?? 0) + $count;
    }
}
print_r($counts);
```

Comment: I updated the benchmark to take into account your proposal (same as KIKO). Performance is still far from good but the best so far. However the memory usage will probably not be compatible with the project.